# Django Class Media js Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: python, django

when importing a local js file to add javascript functionalities to admin, you may face this error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 1):

verify adding a comma at the end of *js tuple*.

doesn't work:

```
class Media:
    js=('path/to/file.js')
```

works:

```
class Media:
    js=('path/to/file.js',)
```